# Let statement throws error on assigning a form to a variable

Tags: elisp

```
(let (lineStr (thing-at-point 'line t))
   (body-form......))
```

throws the error,

```
call-interactively: `let' bindings can have only one value-form: thing-at-point, (quote line), t [2 times]
```

Can't a let variable take a elisp form, and `eval` the form, get its value assigned?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the documentation: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `let` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
let is a special form in `C source code'.

(let VARLIST BODY...)

Bind variables according to VARLIST then eval BODY.
The value of the last form in BODY is returned.
Each element of VARLIST is a symbol (which is bound to nil)
or a list (SYMBOL VALUEFORM) (which binds SYMBOL to the value of VALUEFORM).
All the VALUEFORMs are evalled before any symbols are bound.
```

So `VARLIST` is a list:

```el
(let (...)
  BODY)
```

And *elements which bind values* are also lists:

```el
(let ((SYMBOL VALUEFORM)
      (SYMBOL VALUEFORM))
  BODY)
```

Answer (score 9):

You're missing a necessary set of parentheses around the VARLIST.  Your code should look like this:

`(let ((lineStr (thing-at-point 'line t)))
   (body-form......))`

(See the documentation for 'let' at 'C-h f let'.)  The purpose of the VARLIST being a list is to allow multiple variables to be bound within a single 'let'.  The extra parentheses separate the VARLIST from the BODY.